# Set Wordpress TinyMCE Editor To Readonly

Tags: plugins, tinymce

I am trying to disable the tinyMCEeditor in wordpress so it is `readonly` if the post has already been published. I already have the logic for determining if the post is published (by using `$post` object's `post_status` variable)but I have not found a solution for setting the `readonly` parameter in tinyMCE to `true`.

[Cross-Post from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946391/set-tinymce-editor-param-after-initialized)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hook into `tiny_mce_before_init` to modify the TinyMCE arguments to set the `readonly` attribute.

For example (using PHP 5.3):

```
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', function( $args ) {

    // do you existing check for published here
    if ( 1 == 1 )
         $args['readonly'] = 1;

    return $args;
} );
```

This will make the TinyMCE readonly, however it won't make the HTML editor readonly (that's not TinyMCE) and it also won't stop people using the Media Upload to insert images. However, that might not be an issue - because I would recommend you implement some server-side checking to prevent edits, as it's always possible for someone to send whatever content they want from the browser by manipulating the DOM etc.